# Enqueue scripts in the footer

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I'm trying to modify a plugin for enqueue scripts in the footer, because my jQuery link is in the footer.

The plugin:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fjgwpp_addCSSandJS');
function fjgwpp_addCSSandJS() {

    //Register scripts
    wp_register_script(
        'justifiedGallery', 
        plugins_url('js/jquery.justifiedGallery.min.js', __FILE__)
    );
    wp_register_script(
        'flickrJustifiedGalleryWPPlugin', 
        plugins_url('js/flickrJustifiedGalleryWPPlugin.js', __FILE__)
    );
    wp_register_script(
        'colorbox', 
        plugins_url('lightboxes/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js', __FILE__)
    );

    if (fjgwpp_getOption('provideSwipebox')) {
        wp_register_script(
            'swipebox', 
            plugins_url('lightboxes/swipebox/js/jquery.swipebox.min.js', __FILE__)
        );
    }

    //Enqueue scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('justifiedGallery');
    wp_enqueue_script('flickrJustifiedGalleryWPPlugin');
    if (fjgwpp_getOption('provideColorbox')) {wp_enqueue_script('colorbox');
    }
    if (fjgwpp_getOption('provideSwipebox')) {
        wp_enqueue_script('swipebox');
    }
}
```

I tried to set `$in_footer = true` for all `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('justifiedGallery', true);
```

But the scripts are still printing inside the `<head>`.

**UPDATE**

I change `wp_register_script` for:

```
wp_register_script('flickrJustifiedGalleryWPPlugin', plugins_url('js/flickrJustifiedGalleryWPPlugin.js', __FILE__), '', '', true);
```

And now the scripts are loaded on footer. But appears an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQueryFJGWPP is not defined

Comment: The edit you've provided doesn't seem to be caused by any of the code you've posted. Can you start a new question? And it looks like that's a PHP error, it probably belongs on the regular StackExchange site.

Answer (score 6):

From http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script:

> `<?php wp_register_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?>`

This means you need to add the `$deps` and `$ver` values to `wp_register_script()` in order to set `$in_footer`. Like this:

```
wp_register_script(
    'justifiedGallery', 
    plugins_url('js/jquery.justifiedGallery.min.js', __FILE__),
    false, // or array(), or array('jquery') if this depends on jQuery
    '1.0', // or your plugin version, or the version of the js file
    true   // $in_footer
);
```

Comment: Please, see my update above.